# For Each Cell Loop - Excel JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

[image]

In the following VBA code, I debug.print each cell value. Using the data in the picture, my answer appears like this.

```
Sub loopAndDebugPrintEachCell()
Dim cl As Object
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cl In .Range("A1:D2")
        Debug.Print cl.Value
    Next cl
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

I am trying to reiterate this code in JavaScript and I figured out a solution, but I am not sure that this is the most efficient way. I am getting the exact same answer, but is there a more advantageous way to loop through a range?

```
  loopAndConsoleLogEachCell = async () => {
    try {
      await Excel.run(async context => {
        const range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("A1:D2");
        range.load(["columnCount", "rowCount"]);
        await context.sync();
        let i = 0;
        let rowC = 0;
        do {
          let loopRng = range.getAbsoluteResizedRange(1, 1).getOffsetRange(rowC, i).load(["values"]);
          await context.sync();
          console.log(`${loopRng.values} `);
          let rangeColCount = Math.floor(((range.columnCount) / 2) + 1);
          if (rowC < (range.rowCount) && i == (rangeColCount)) {
            rowC++;
            i = 0;
          } else {
            i++;
          }
        }
        while (rowC < range.rowCount && i < range.columnCount);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: In addition to @RaymondLu answer, don't have a `context.sync` in a loop. For details about how to avoid this, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern?view=word-js-preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the value of each cell in the range, you could use `range.values` API

Here is the sample code for getting the values for the range

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const range = sheet.getRange("B2:E6");
    range.load("text");
    range.load("values");

    await context.sync();
    console.log(range.values);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(range.text, null, 4));
  });
```

The document can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#values

Answer (score 1):

Update:

My original answer searched the entire range starting at row/col 0/0, but I quickly realized a few "gotchas" based on the code (copied from MS somewhere...).

Here is an example where I'm only searching in a column and I'm not starting at row 0.

A few notes:

- I changed `r` to `i` because `r` makes you think `row` but really, its the index of the range which is zero indexed, but could start at row 42.
- So, when accessing `values` for `B2` inside of say `Range("B2:B5")` your value starts with `.values[0][0]`.
- To get the value of Cell `C2` inside `Range("B2:C5")` your value would be `.values[0][1]`. (0 = first row of RANGE and 1 = second col in range).
- Using `foo.length` inside loop declaration re-calculates the variable each iteration of the loop, for readability and efficiency, declare your start end variables before loop.

  ```
        var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        var rng = ws.getRange("B2:B5");

        rng .load(["rowCount", "values"]);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                var RowCount = rng.rowCount  
                for (var i = 0; i < RowCount; ++i) {
                    var rcellval = rng .values[i][0]
                    console.log(rcellval)
                }
            })
  ```

---

Here is an example I used to iterate over a range, only using one `context.sync()` to find a cell match via `RegEx` which should illustrate how to use a `For Each Cell` loop. Keep in mind I am new to JS as well, but I believe this is proper method.

```
function Bool_RegEx(rexp, findstr) {
    return rexp.test(findstr)
}
```

---

```
function Make_FakeData(context) {
    var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var rng = ws.getRange("A1:D5");
    rng.values = "TESTDATA";

    var rng = ws.getRange("A5");
    rng.values = "AB12345678"
    return context;
}
```

---

```
export async function helloworld(event) {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {
            //Start Func
            Make_FakeData(context);

            var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            var rng = ws.getRange("A1:D5");
            rng.load(["columnCount", "rowCount", "values"]);

            let rexp = new RegExp('[a-z]{2}[0-9]{8}', 'i');
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    for (var r = 0; r < rng.rowCount; ++r) {
                        for (var c = 0; c < rng.columnCount; ++c) { 
                        var rcellval = rng.values[r][c];
                        console.log("r = " + r);
                        console.log("c = " + c);
                        console.log("rcellval = " + rcellval);
                        if (Bool_RegEx(rexp, rcellval) === true) {
                            console.log("RegEx Match in Row r" + r + ", Col " + c);
                            console.log("RegEx Match rcellval = " + rcellval);
                        }
                    }
                }

                })

            //End Func
            await context.sync();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    event.completed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA allows you to access every cell on the iteration using the for loop. What I did in TypeScript to replicate this for a range was loading the properties of columns and rows and storing the values in variables:

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
range.load(["columnIndex", "columnCount", "rowCount", "rowIndex"]);
let col_1 = range.columnIndex; //first column index
let nc = range.columnCount; //number of columns
let row_1 = range.rowIndex; //first row
let nr = range.rowCount; //number of rows
```

Then you can access each cell with two for loops:

```
for (let r = 0; r < nr; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < nc; c++) {
         cell = sheet.getCell(r + row_1, c + col_1);
         cell.load(["address", "values", "formulasR1C1", "format"]);
         await context.sync();
         let cell_add = cell.address;
         let cell_val = cell.values[0][0]; //values of a cell/range is always a matrix
         if (cell_val <= 5) {
         //do something
         }
      }
  };
```

The code might not be the best, but it worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this! This definitely works, but per Rick’s comment above, you should avoid context.sync in a loop.

Comment: Yes, I just realised later! I'll get deep in the working of the code and I'll  try to avoid unnecessary synchronizations.